# Join two table order by date and set 0 value to the empty column

Tags: mysql

I have two different tables: First table is used to send the data for the user who claimed their products

```
  +---+-----------+----------+--------+
  |id |  claimed  |  date    | ref no |
  +---+-----------+----------+--------+
  | 1 |   20      | 20-02-13 | sda123 |
  | 2 |   30      | 22-02-13 | sda123 |
  | 3 |   40      | 24-02-13 | sda123 |
  | 4 |   50      | 26-02-13 | sda123 |
  +---+-----------+----------+--------+
```

And the second table is used to save the data for the user who added the products.

```
  +---+-----------+----------+--------+
  |id |  added    |  date    | ref no |
  +---+-----------+----------+--------+
  | 1 |   15      | 21-02-13 | sda123 |
  | 2 |   25      | 23-02-13 | sda123 |
  | 3 |   35      | 25-02-13 | sda123 |
  | 4 |   45      | 27-02-13 | sda123 |
  +---+-----------+----------+--------+
```

Now I want to join the two tables. But I want to join them based on the date. If at the date mentioned the user only added the product, then in the column of claimed will be set as 0, and vice verca.

History For  **sda123**

```
  +-----------+----------+------------+
  |  claimed  |  added   |    date    |   
  +-----------+----------+------------+
  |   20      |     0    |  20-02-13  |
  |   0       |    15    |  21-02-13  |
  |   30      |     0    |  22-02-13  |
  |   0       |    25    |  23-02-13  |
  +-----------+----------+------------+
```

Can anybody help me how to do this in sql? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Actually it is. But for now I used it manually.

Comment: Yes it shows 2013-02-20 at the real table. But because it too long if i write it here, I edit it.

Comment: No it doesn't have any significance. It is just as the number of the row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You select the union of all dates and then join it with both tables to get the summations:

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(`claimed`), 0) `claimed`, COALESCE(SUM(`added`),0) `added`, `date`
FROM (SELECT `date` FROM `claimed` UNION SELECT `date` FROM `added`) `dates`
LEFT JOIN `claimed` USING (`date`)
LEFT JOIN `added` USING (`date`)
GROUP BY `date`
ORDER BY `date`;
```

I'm using `COALESCE()` to prevent `NULL` from showing up in the results; instead, it will show `0` (if the corresponding value from either table doesn't exist for that particular date). Instead of `COALESCE()` you can also use `IFNULL()` because there's only one value to evaluate.

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/93046/2)

Comment: Jack, How to change 0 into `dash` (`-`) in the result?

Answer (score 0):

use a LEFT JOIN and replace the NULLs with zeros, like this:

```
SELECT CLAIMED.claimed, IFNULL(ADDED.added, 0), CLAIMED.date 
FROM CLAIMED JOIN ADDED ON CLAIMED.date=ADDED.date
```

I used caps for table names, since you didn't specify them.